# How to disable ESLint jsx-a11y/alt-text for entire project

Tags: javascript, next.js, eslint

Does anyone know how to disable this in the eslintrc.json file for entire Next.js project?

[image]

I have added this, but it does not work:

```
{
  "extends": ["next/core-web-vitals", "prettier"],
  "rules": {
    "prefer-const": "error",
    "indent": ["error", 2],
    "jsx-a11y/img-has-alt": "off"
  }
}
```

Comment: I doesn't sound like a good idea to disable it, especialy for the whole project. I'm wondering why do you think it's not important to add the `alt` to images, like the a11y deems it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead: `"jsx-a11y/alt-text": [0]`, see the [docs](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/main/docs/rules/alt-text.md) for more info